# Perl Script to Monitor URL Using  proxy credentials?

Tags: perl-module, mod-perl2

Please help on the following code, this is not working in our environment.

```
use LWP;
use strict;
my $url = 'http://google.com';
my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'mypassword';
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new('Mozilla');
$browser->credentials("172.18.124.11:80","something.co.in",$username=>$password);
$browser->timeout(10);
my $response=$browser->get($url);
print $response->content;
```

OUTPUT :

Can't connect to google.com:80 (timeout)

LWP::Protocol::http::Socket: connect: timeout at C:/Perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.p m line 51.

OS: windows XP

Regards, Gaurav

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please consider marking an answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a HTTP proxy at 172.18.124.11? I assume LWP is not using the proxy. You might want to use `env_proxy => 1` with the `new()` call.

You also have a mod-perl2 tag in this question. If this code runs inside mod-perl2, it's possible that the `http_proxy` env variable is not visible to the code. You can check this eg. by printing `$browser->proxy('http')`.

Or just set the proxy with `$browser->proxy('http', '172.18.124.11')`;

Also, I assume you don't have `use warnings` on, because `new()` takes a hash, not just a string. It's a good idea to **always** enable warnings. That will save you lots of trouble.